# How can I connect to Apache Spark Stream in Mule?

Tags: apache-spark, mule, spark-streaming, anypoint-studio

I need to connect to Apache Spark Stream where input will come from Kafka and processed data then go to Cassandra. I tried to find Spark connector but didn't get any result.
Is there any custom connector available ?
How can I use Apache Spark Stream in Mule ?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to connect to Apache Spark Stream where input will **come from**
>   **Kafka** and processed data then go to Cassandra.

So you need not a Spark connector, but Kafka connector: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/kafka-connector

Comment: I need to do some processing in Spark that's why I need Spark Stream.